# jquery is not laoding in python flask app

Tags: python, jquery, flask

Hello i dont know why the jquery is not loading in my flask app ? even though i have downloaded the jquery and add in js folder

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link href="{{url_for('static', filename = 'css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{url_for('static', filename = 'myicon.ico' )}}">
<script type=text/javascript src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{url_for('static', filename = 'js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
```

Comment: Please show HTML you get into the browser

Answer (score 0):

`type=text/javascript` should be `type="text/javascript"` in line referencing jQuery.